# I have been asked to redesign a report generation tool

Tags: software

the client has written a requirements document and has constructed use cases. There has been no user research.

The interface needs to be reviewed by me and a new set of wireframes drawn up that correct problems with the existing interface and incorporate all the new changes in the requirements doc.

My initial review of the system indicate that it has highly unorthodox UX, including non standard controls (eg double click menu items instead of single click); complex IA etc. I can fix a lot of the problems with a heuristic review but without research data cannot validate the use cases and critically, cannot identify the core use cases for the project

How do I go about identifying the core use cases for the system without research data? I cannot even call upon competitors to help; I am really super stuck.

edit
the reports are detail attributes associated with elements in the construction industry eg time built, time worked on build, team members on build; but there are hundreds of attributes.

I have no access to any other data that might help me eg GA

Answer (score 2):

Heuristic evaluation seems like a good start. Can you just not call one or two users to validate your findings? If they do not provide / support user contact; or your contact with anyone who actually met the users or makes business decisions; I would just go along with benchmark (google anaylthics, other reporting tools such as diet watching stuff, running apps, banking apps, etc...) and the heuristic evaluation. 
What kind of reports are you working on, can you elaborate what are the key functions?

Comment: I've edited my question a bit. Wont help much ;)

Comment: colmq I guess you have to invest on a bit of personal relationships after you come up with an initial design... So you befriend an innovative minded person from the company and let them review your design with you... Good luck!